# Execute a simple API using perl script

Tags: perl

I'm trying to execute a API using a perl script. I'm in initial stage and below is the simple script I got which is not working. I have used *get* command to execute the API. But I'm not sure it will work or not. In fact I'm not able to find the get command will work not because I'm getting a different error in this code . This script gives me error like below

```
Use of uninitialized value $api_content in print at igmp.pl line 11.
```

Here is the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl   
use strict; 
use warnings;  
use LWP::Simple;  

my $api_content;

my $api = 'https://admin:Macin123@12.34.45.67/set_param?init.snmp_ver=3&mib.save'; 
$api_content = get($api); 

print $api_content;
```

Please let me know if there is a command is will be useful for executing this simple API. Basically I need to set the value of snmp to 3 and save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is, that you need to use LWP::UserAgent directly so you can see the details of the response:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get('https://admin:Macin123@12.34.45.67/set_param?init.snmp_ver=3&mib.save');

if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```